# Use of multiple models extending built-in User model in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I want to use multiple models extending the built-in User model. According to their docs https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Managing-users.html , this is only possible with version 3.3.0 and above...when i check my version using 'npm ls loopback -V' I get 3.25.0. How can i get the required version 3.3.0 and above?

Comment: Your version 3.25.0 is already above 3.3.0.

Comment: It seems the last version is the 3.25.0. Multiple user models feature is already available in the last version, I made some experimentation a few weeks ago.

Comment: Guys those answers were helpful...I have done the experimentation and it works.